# How to query documents where the query should have an and clause?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

How do I use the nodejs driver for elastic search do achieve the following scenario. The scenario is that I have to update all documents in a "title" index where the tvSeries id is given and where the tvSeriesNumber is given?

I only want to match documents that fulfill both queries. I know that I should be using the client.updateByQuery method but I'm not sure what to put for the query body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? You probably need to modify the script in order to update whatever fields you want to.

```
client.updateByQuery({ 
       index: "title",
       type: "type",
       body: { 
          "query": { 
             "bool": { 
               "filter": [
                 { "term": { "tvSeriesId": 123} },
                 { "term": { "tvSeriesNumber": 456} }
               ]
             } 
          }, 
          "script": { 
             "inline": "ctx._source.xyz = 'abc'"
          }
       }
    }, function(err, res) { 
        if (err) { 
           reportError(err) 
        } 
        cb(err, res)
    }
)
```

Comment: This works! Thanks man. The Javascript api documentation is pretty lackluster with examples. You're a life saver :)

Comment: The JS docs is pretty much focused on how to make the `updateByQuery` call, for anything that you need to put inside the body, you should consult the Query DSL documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html